# Fail to build Yocto extensible SDK

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, yocto-recipe

I'm new to Yocto and I've been trying to setup for developing with `devtool`.

I've followed the instructions from from the [Yocto Linux Kernel Development Manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/kernel-dev/common.html#getting-ready-to-develop-using-devtool), but I've made a change to *Step #2*, setting `MACHINE = stm32mp1` since I'm targeting the [STM32MP157D-DK1](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32mp157d-dk1.html). However, *Step #5* fails, where it asks you to build the SDK using the command `bitbake core-image-minimal -c populate_sdk_ext` with the following error:

```
ERROR: buildtools-tarball-1.0-r0 do_populate_sdk: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/myusername/Projects/yocto/stm32mp1-build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/buildtools-tarball/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /home/myusername/Projects/yocto/stm32mp1-build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/buildtools-tarball/1.0-r0/sdk/image/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/myusername/Projects/yocto/stm32mp1-build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/buildtools-tarball/1.0-r0/sdk/image/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/home/myusername/Projects/yocto/stm32mp1-build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/buildtools-tarball/1.0-r0/sdk/image --setopt=logdir=/home/myusername/Projects/yocto/stm32mp1-build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/buildtools-tarball/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/myusername/Projects/yocto/stm32mp1-build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/buildtools-tarball/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo --nogpgcheck install nativesdk-binutils nativesdk-buildtools-perl-dummy nativesdk-ca-certificates nativesdk-chrpath nativesdk-fiptool-stm32mp nativesdk-gcc-arm-none-eabi nativesdk-git nativesdk-git-perltools nativesdk-glibc-gconv-utf-16 nativesdk-glibc-gconv-utf-32 nativesdk-libnss-nis nativesdk-make nativesdk-mtools nativesdk-ncurses-libncursesw nativesdk-ncurses-terminfo-base nativesdk-openocd-stm32mp nativesdk-openssl-dev nativesdk-optee-sdk nativesdk-patch nativesdk-pigz nativesdk-python3-core nativesdk-python3-git nativesdk-python3-jinja2 nativesdk-python3-misc nativesdk-python3-modules nativesdk-python3-pycrypto nativesdk-python3-pycryptodomex nativesdk-python3-pyelftools nativesdk-python3-subunit nativesdk-python3-testtools nativesdk-rpcsvc-proto nativesdk-sdcard-raw-tools nativesdk-stm32wrapper4dbg nativesdk-svd-tools nativesdk-tar nativesdk-texinfo nativesdk-u-boot-mkimage nativesdk-wayland nativesdk-wget' returned 1:
DNF version: 4.2.2
cachedir: /home/myusername/Projects/yocto/stm32mp1-build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/buildtools-tarball/1.0-r0/sdk/image/var/cache/dnf
Added oe-repo repo from /home/myusername/Projects/yocto/stm32mp1-build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/buildtools-tarball/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
not found other for: 
not found modules for: 
not found deltainfo for: 
not found updateinfo for: 
oe-repo: using metadata from Sun 02 Jan 2022 01:50:06 AM UTC.
No module defaults found
--> Starting dependency resolution
--> Finished dependency resolution
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) needed by nativesdk-gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-r0.x86_64_nativesdk
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/myusername/Projects/yocto/stm32mp1-build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/buildtools-tarball/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sdk.2232965
ERROR: Task (/home/myusername/Projects/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/meta/buildtools-tarball.bb:do_populate_sdk) failed with exit code '1'
```

Based on similar issues I've found on the internet, I've tried adding the layer [meta-python2](https://git.openembedded.org/meta-python2), and setting `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-dev"` in my `local.conf`. However, the issue persists.

I'm on Linux Mint 20.2, which is based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Below are the active layers:

```
layer                 path                                      priority
==========================================================================
meta                  /home/myusername/Projects/yocto/poky/meta       5
meta-poky             /home/myusername/Projects/yocto/poky/meta-poky  5
meta-yocto-bsp        /home/myusername/Projects/yocto/poky/meta-yocto-bsp  5
meta-oe               /home/myusername/Projects/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-oe  6
meta-python           /home/myusername/Projects/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-python  7
meta-st-stm32mp       /home/myusername/Projects/yocto//meta-st-stm32mp  6
meta-python2          /home/myusername/Projects/yocto/meta-python2    7
```

I've confirmed that `bitbake core-image-minimal -c populate_sdk_ext` succeeds with `MACHINE = qemux86`.

Just `bitbake core-image-minimal` command succeeds with `MACHINE = stm32mp1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the build issue. It required adding `meta-python2` as I did; but instead of `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-dev"`, `TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append = " nativesdk-python-core"` is needed instead in `local.conf`.